Должен ли эндпоинт контроллера Asp.Net быть асинхронным
Есть мнение что эндпоинт контроллера в ASP.NET API должен быть асинхронным в любом случае, но что делать если в нем нет вызова await ?

Вариант оставить async но тогда будет предупреждение CS1998

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetTaskResult()
{
    //CS1998 Нет await
    var result = GetResSync();
    return Ok(result);
}


Вариант с возвратом Task

[HttpGet]
public Task<ActionResult<string>> GetTaskResult()
{
    var result = GetResSync();
    ActionResult<string> actionResult = Ok(result);
    return Task.FromResult(actionResult);
}


Вариант сделать синхронно. UPD Действительно, оба примера синхронны как отметил EvgeniyZ. Скажем вариант без оборачивания в Task

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> GetResult()
{
    var result = GetResSync();
    ActionResult<string> actionResult = Ok(result);
    return actionResult;
}

Какой вариант более предпочтительный?

Если не планируется сделать потом асинхронный вариант, то я бы оставил синхронный метод, чтобы никого не путать. А так ещё можно в первом варианте сделать await Task.CompletedTask; и ругаться не будет, что у вас нет await в методе. )

Предпочтительнее асинхронный

В вашем коде оба варианта синхронны, они оба делают одну синхронную задачу, ждут ее, а значит разницы между ними по сути и нет. "Что лучше" - если есть возможность, всегда лучше делать асинхронные задачи, ибо тем самым ваши потоки не блокируются при ожидании Task, что позволяет им выполнять другие задачи, что в свою очередь существенно повышает производительность. Но все надо делать конечно с умом. В документации есть пункт про то, что выбрать.

@EvgeniyZ тогда еще уточню будет ли преимущество async + await Task.FromResult(..)  перед  public ActionResult GetResult()  ?

С точки зрения C#, нет, ибо это все еще один и тот-же, синхронный код, у вас все так-же есть GetResSync, которая может заблокировать целый поток на время ее выполнения. Преимущества будут тогда, когда вы тяжелые операции сделаете асинхронными и асинхронно их запустите при помощи async и await, вот тогда у вас будет полноценный асинхронный метод. Как под капотом ASP, не знаю, может что оптимизирует (но вряд-ли).

Что делает метод GetResSync? Как долго? Что при этом потребляется: CPU или IO?

@AlexanderPetrov допустим CPU операции мапит большие коллекции. По времени думаю до пол сек

Оставляйте вариант 3, синхронный.

В асинхронности есть смысл тогда, когда используются асинхронные операции. Ни в одном из предложенных вариантов у вас их нет.
Следовательно наиболее оптимальным выглядит синхронный вариант.
Ключевое слово async не делает метод асинхронным. Вот примеры
Синхронный метод (метод, всегда завершающийся синхронно)
private async Task Method1()
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}

Асинхронный метод (метод, возвращающий незавешенный Task)
private Task Method2()
{
    return Task.Delay(100);
}

Первый синхронный потому что в 100% случаев Task, который он вернёт, уже будет завершён. То есть метод завершится синхронно. Не нужно писать методы с асинхронной сигнатурой, но выполняющиеся синхронно, это ошибка.
Второй асинхронный, потому что вернёт незавершённый Task, чем инициирует асинхронное ожидание, если написать await Method2().
Поэтому нет смысла использовать async без await.
Что касается Task.FromResult, это полезно, когда вы вынуждены вернуть Task, например при реализации интерфейса или наследовании класса, но асинхронной работы в методе неоткуда взять или не требуется. В вашем конкретном случае есть синхронный вариант, поэтому использовать Task.FromResult нет смысла.

Чисто придирки ради, ваш асинхронный метод не совсем асинхронный,  он ничего не ожидает,  просто возвращает результат синхронного вызова. Но вцелом плюс конечно

@tym32167 будет ли метод асинхронный async + await Task.CompletedTask() ?. Точнее спасет ли это как то от блокировки

await completed task - это не асинхронный код,  вы пытаетесь ожидать уже завершенную операцию, а значит код выполнится синхронно, переключений контекста не будет, а значит и блокировки не будет @Greg9303

@Greg9303 CompletedTask уже завершён, он не вызывает блокировку. Ему хоть await, хоть .Result, он просто моментально и синхронно выплюнет результат.

@tym32167 это вопрос тонкостей терминологии. С моей колокольни смысл асинхронности в возможности таска, который возвращается из метода завершиться асинхронно. Может я перегибаю конечно, но если метод либо не возвращает ничего, к чему можно await прикрутить, либо возвращает завершённый таск, то он не является по факту асинхронным. С точки зрения синтаксиса C# асинхронным методом считается любой метод, возвращающий awaitable структуру или класс. То есть я немного глубже копаю, чем просто синтаксис. Добавил пояснение в ответ.
